# React Component Function not working onClick button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

the component

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.fuelD = props.fuelD; //array of objects
   this.state={
     averageFuelConsumption:0,
   }
}
```

the custom function

```
calcAverage = () => {
  console.log("something")
}
```

the button

```
<button onClick={()=>this.calcAverage)}>Click</button>
```

clicking the button .. resolves to nothing in the console...
if I  do this .. it works

```
<button onClick={()=>console.log("something")}>Click</button>
```

I tried bind(this) on  the function

1.in the `constructor()` - not working

2.in the `onClick` - not working

Comment: Try just using: <button onClick={ this.calcAverage }>Click</button>

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to either

`<button onClick={this.calcAverage}>Click</button>`

or

`<button onClick={() => this.calcAverage()}>Click</button>`

Currently, your `onClick` handler is just returning a reference to `this.calcAverage`, not actually calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple syntax error in `onClick={()=>this.calcAverage)}`. Note the closing paren `)` which is unbalanced.

What you probably want is `onClick={() => this.calcAlverage()}`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

**Solution 1**

`<button onClick={() => this.calcAverage()}>Click</button>`

*You missed the `()` in your code.*

Should you need `event` (*in case `event.stopPropagation()` is necessary,  for example*):

`<button onClick={(event) => this.calcAverage(event)}>Click</button>`

**Solution 2**

`<button onClick={this.calcAverage}>Click</button>`

This is the recommended one since using arrow function to bind the event (*as in Solution 1*) could cause performance issues in the future. Every time your component gets rendered it recreates the same event over and over.

Comment: onClick={this.calcAverage} resolves in a render loop ...
onClick={() => this.calcAverage())} works perfect .. but why  on  places i  need the () and in  places i dont ... on  calling function onClick

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.calcAverage)}>Click</button>
```

With

```
<button onClick={this.calcAverage)}>Click</button>
```

In the former you're returning the reference of function within an anonymous function instead of invoking it.